# swift cast array of PFObject to Custom PFSubclass

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfobject, pfsubclassing

i'm casting an array of pfobject in PFQueryTableViewController, but got an error..
which is the corrent way?

```
override func objectsDidLoad(error: NSError?) {
    super.objectsDidLoad(error)

    var totalSeconds: Int = 0

    for record in objects as! [Record] {
        totalSeconds += Int(record.totalDuration)
    }

    navigationItem.prompt = MyUtility.stringFromSeconds(totalSeconds)
}
```

record must be an "Record" object conform to protocol PFSubclassing

Now, when the objects finish loading the debugger say error

> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Comment: did you register your subclassed object? `subclassedObject.registerSubclass()`

Comment: yes, the Record Class is initialized

Answer (score 0):

I solved  in this way:

```
override func objectsDidLoad(error: NSError?) {
    super.objectsDidLoad(error)

    var totalSeconds: Int = 0
    let records = objects as! [Record]

    for record in records{
        totalSeconds += Int(record.totalDuration)
    }

    navigationItem.prompt = MyUtility.stringFromSeconds(totalSeconds)
}
```

There is a faster way to do the same thing?